# can't make responsive sections in html

Tags: css, html, sections

I have a web page which includes some sections in it.

I use this css class for sections for making it reponsive, but It's not responsive, that much. Some monitors have more blank space in the section, some of them fit to the monitor.

```
    .section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I believe I should change `section` class in `css`. But don't know what to change.

Here is the `html` code for sections :

```
    <div class="section" id="1">
<section>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1>Line 1</h1>
<h1>Line 2</h1>
<h1>Line 3</h1>
<h1>Line 4</h1>
<h1>Line 5</h1>
<h1>Line 6</h1>
</section>
</div>
```

**Edit** : The width of the sections are great but the height not good that much. some device shows all height of the sections and some of them show part of them and some are fit.

**Some devices show line 1 and line 2 and line 3 some show all of them. Different.**

In smaller devices show all lines with lot of blank spaces which means can use more content for it but in larger devices only show three lines or even less.

I want to make all sections and their content responsive and want to use `css` in `section` class.

How can I make the sections responsive for all devices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the HTML? Can you post your code and not just a snippet?

Comment: @dowomenfart I just gave you the html code

Answer (score 0):

For using % value in height, you need to ensure that every ancestor of the element is also using % value for the height. For width % value would work just fine and you would be easily able to achieve responsiveness.

BTW, why don't you try out responsive frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation?

Comment: The width of the sections are great but the height not good that much. some device shows all height of the sections and some of them show part of them and some are fit.

Comment: Then I guess, you have to resort to fixed height or % values for every ancestor of the responsive element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'height: 100%;', try 'height: auto;'.
I am not quite sure what you want to achieve with the sections, but I am assuming that you want to achieve consistent heights depending on your content.